# If $A$ is idempotent then $(I-A)$ is also idempotent

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

I've been under the impression that matrices cannot be treated like normal algebra. This is a fundamental concept, of course, and I've known it for some time. Generally such a notion would imply $(A-B)^2 ≠ A^2 - 2AB + B^2$, right?

However a question in a university course has caused me some confusion:

> Prove that if $A$ is idempotent, then so is $(I-A)$.

The worked solution is as follows:

"$A$ is idempotent if $A^2 = A$. Consider $(I-A)^2$. We have

$$(I-A)^2 = (I-A)(I-A) = I^2 - 2AI + A^2 = I - 2A + A = I - A$$

Therefore $(I-A)^2 = (I-A)$, thus $(I-A)$ is idempotent if $A$ is idempotent."

Perhaps there is some 'loophole', if you will, when it comes to the identity matrix that allows us to perform these distributions in certain matrix situations. If so, would someone please be able to provide a simple proof - just something to give me some understanding behind the origins of the concept? Thank you.

Comment: Hint: For the formula $(A-B)^2=A^2 - 2 AB +B^2$ you want $A$ and $B$ to commute, i.e., $AB=BA$. Is this the case in general? Is it the case in your example?

Comment: The word you want is "[commutativity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutative_property)". Indeed, matrix multiplication is not commutative in general, but *some* matrices do commute. In particular, the identity matrix $I$ commutes with all matrices, and even better, we know that $IA = AI = A$, for any $A$ (by definition of $I$).

Comment: Ah right, so that is the only issue in applying distributive laws? I thought there may have been something more. But yes, I see, IA=AI. More simple than I imagined. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @Questionsaboutmath Yes, you have distributivity, i.e. $A(B+C)=AB+AC$, so if you open the brackets you get $(A-B)(A-B)=A^2-BA-AB+B^2$ which provides the formula if $AB=BA$.

Answer (score 1):

We know that for any $n \times n$ matrix $A$, $I_n A = A I_n = A$, where $I_n$ is the $n \times n$ identity matrix. We then have:
$$ (I_n - A)^2 = (I_n - A)(I_n - A)$$
$$ = I_n^2 - I_n A - A I_n + A^2. $$
$$ = I_n - 2 A + A^2.$$

Answer (score 0):

More generally, since matrix multiplication is distributive, you have for *any* matrices of the same dimensions
$$(A-B)^2=(A-B)(A-B) = A(A-B)-B(A-B)=A^2-AB-BA+B^2.\tag{1}$$

If the matrices $A$ and $B$ *commute*, i.e., if they are such matrices that $AB=BA$, then you have
$$(A-B)^2=A^2-2AB+B^2.\tag{2}$$

One example is if one of the two matrices is the identity matrix $I$. It would also work, for example, if $B=A^2$. There are many other examples.

But, as you correctly said, you have to keep in mind that $(2)$ is not true for arbitrary matrices, only for some of them. (As opposed to $(1)$, which holds for any matrices.)